# How to obtain the full file path when using InputFile in Blazor Server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I need to be able to extract the full file name, including the path when the user selects a file using my InputFile element.

So, as an example, using this

`<InputFile  OnChange="FileSelected" />`

I can see the filename in the event handler like so

`void FileSelected(InputFileChangeEventArgs eventArgs)`
`{`

`//eventArgs.File.Name has just the name of the file, e.g. ABC.csv but I need the full path like c:\userfolder\ABC.csv`

but after various googling attempts, I haven't been able to figure out how to get the full file name.

The purpose here is to present the user with a file dialog box where they could pick a file and then I could load a few other files that are needed using the full file path.

Thanks

Comment: Browsers generally don't send this information to the server.  Because the server doesn't need this information, so there's no reason to provide extra details about the user's file system that could potentially be exploited in some way.  Why do you think you need the client-side file path on the server?

Comment: I'd say this is not possible for security reasons. File full path should not go to the server

Comment: Explain why, in any universe, you need the SERVER to know anything about the CLIENT'S file system.  If I found out that any web browser would even theoretically allow this, I'd change browsers right away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> then I could load a few other files that are needed using the full file path

Nope.

The server cannot read from the client’s file system.  Any files that need to be sent to the server, the client needs to send them.

Even the client-side code is very restricted by the browser’s sandboxed environment.  The user needs to supply the file in order to grant permission.  See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File

You’ll likely need to re-think the use case.  Because browsers specifically don’t allow what you want to do.

Comment: This would be an internal-only web interface, allowing a user to upload an XML schema, which in turn may include links to other XML/XSD files, stored in child and parent directories relative to original file's path. The originally uploaded file is parsed to determine which files to extract. I just realized that the user could zip up the whole folder and upload to zip to the server and then the extraction and the parent/child directories can be processed by blazor

Comment: @LePrinceDeDhump: Unless by “internal only” you mean that each user is going to have their own web server instance running on their own workstation (which would be highly unusual and unnecessarily difficult to maintain) then the problem remains the same.  But yes, zipping the folder and uploading the zip file would certainly work.

Answer (score 3):

try this....

```
public void OnChangeUpload(UploadChangeEventArgs args) 
{ 
    foreach (var file in args.Files) 
    { 
        var path = Path.GetFullPath("wwwroot\\Images\\") + file.FileInfo.Name; 
        FileStream filestream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write); 
        file.Stream.WriteTo(filestream); 
        filestream.Close(); 
        file.Stream.Close(); 
        pathUrl = path; 
    } 
}
```